# Transfering my background Color into a nother JS-Class

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have a React Native Project with a login.js. In this class i have several Views etc. These Views use Stylesheet, which are defined within the class. Now i tried to extract/transfer the backGround color into a "container class"(values.js) where i can get the color (rgba) and use it in my login.js class. Since i have done this, the color won´t show anything anymore. It´s pure white, and it doesn´t take the color i defined which is some kind of red.

This is my login code:
login.js

```
var Values=require('../values/values');

...
<View style={styles.titleContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.titleText}>{Strings.login}</Text>
</View>
...

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1
},
bg: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: windowSize.width,
    height: windowSize.height
},
titleContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 0.15,
    backgroundColor: Values.Color.COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR,
},
})
```

This is where i have my "color container/color sets":
values.js

```
module.exports = {

API: [
    {
        //API
        API_BASE_URL: "",
        //LOCAL
        API_LOCAL_URL: "http://localhost:1986/",
    }],

Color: [
    {
        COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR: 'rgba(163,63,59,1)',
        ......
        .....
    }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the arrays that you are using as API and Color fields of the exported object. Your exported object contains two fields: API and Color, which are both arrays of objects. So if you want to refer to the color value, something like that will work:

```
Values.Color[0].COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR
```

But probably it's not what you really wanted. Most likely your definition should look like (note that for consistency, probably it's still better to use all capitals in color and values):

```
module.exports={
    API: {
        API_BASE_URL: "",
        ...
    },
    COLOR: {
        COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR: 'rgba(163,63,59,1)',
        ...
    }
}
```

and you should import/refer to it as:

```
var VALUES=require('../values/values');
....

backgroundColor: VALUES.COLOR.COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR,
...
```

Comment: Great thanks! Thats exactly what i wanted...and thanks for the advice to the capitals i will do this in future, it just looks right.